Expressing an assumption that all variables are mutually distinct and come from a specified set
In trying to solve this question using FindInstance, I'd like to know how to elegantly express an assumption that all variables {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i} come from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and are mutually distinct.
Constraints such as PositiveIntegers and such don't help much.

constraints = {Thread[1 <= vars <= 9], Unequal @@ vars, a > b} // Flatten; and the domain is Integers

This is what I sought.  Thanks so much. ($+1$)

Can you please share your solution using FindInstance? Thanks.

@BobHanlon I fully appreciate your comment but I don’t think the condition a>b is necessary or specified in riddle, eg (4-7)^2=(7-4)^2=9. I have learned enormously from your answers over the years.

@ubpdqn - If c is odd then a > b. If c is even then a and b are interchangeable and it suffices to find a > b. You can eliminate the extra condition at will.

A brute-forced solution using Permutations and Pick:
Clear["Global`*"];
vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
perms = Permutations[set, {Length@set}];
sel = (a - b)^c - d == e && f g - h i == 3 /. Thread[vars -> #] & /@ 
   perms;
Pick[perms, sel]




nice  direct translation of "riddle to code". I should have trusted dealing with 9! entries rather then breaking into smaller  parts. +1 :)

Here is an approach to the "riddle" in the hyperlink:
 r = Range[9];
s = Subsets[r, {2}];
d = UpperTriangularize[
   DistanceMatrix[s, 
    DistanceFunction -> (Abs[Times @@ #1 - Times @@ #2] &)], 1];
p = Position[d, 3];
cand = Reverse /@ Select[s[[#]] & /@ p, Intersection @@ # == {} &];
perms[v_] := 
  With[{u = Flatten[v]}, {Permute[u, {}], 
    Permute[u, Cycles[{{1, 2}}]], Permute[u, Cycles[{{3, 4}}]], 
    Permute[u, Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]]}];
cand2 = Join @@ (perms /@ cand)
func[u_] := Module[{sd = Complement[r, u], res},
  res = Select[
    Permutations[sd], (#[[1]] - #[[2]])^#[[3]] == #[[4]] + #[[5]] &];
  Join[#, u] & /@ res
  ]
TableForm[Join @@ (func /@ cand2 /. {} :> Nothing), 
 TableHeadings -> {None, CharacterRange["a", "i"]}]


Comment re: timing of 2 current answers

This answer



@Syed answer (which I voted for):


